# Preventing dupliate form submission.

Tags: html, forms, jsp, submit, page-refresh

I have a form in my jsp file of the eclipse.

the form gets values and inserts them into my database.

I entered the values and pressed the submit button, so the values were inserted into my database.

the problem is: if I refresh the page, the previous values are inserted into my database again, although the inputs are empty.

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

so after the refreshing, the name gets the last value that was inserted.

how can I fix it?

Comment: Use the post-redirect-get pattern?

Comment: @DaveNewton,  thank you!
I found this: http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html 
there is a code. where should I save it? in my servlet.java file? 

"Activate this phaselistener by adding the following lines to the faces-config.xml", but I don't have this file in my project :/

Comment: Are you using JSF? If not, you shouldn't have one. All PRG means is that after you post you redirect to another page; it's not complicated.

Comment: so I have to make two pages that have the same code (the same form), and when the user presses the submit button from first page, submit it and move the user to the second page..
in the second page, if he presses the submit button, submit it and move him to the first page. right? @DaveNewton

Comment: I don't really know; why would you post to a servlet and show the same form again? When you submit, if it's successful, redirect to a new page. If it's the same form, then redirect to the servlet (or the JSP if you're hitting them directly, but ew) that shows the form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit a form only once; don't submit when page is refreshed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269119/submit-a-form-only-once-dont-submit-when-page-is-refreshed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the POST method for HTTP requests that perform an action, and GET for those that only retrieve data. Respond to the POST request by redirecting to a resource that would be requested with GET. That way, the form won't get resubmitted.