# Javascript stops working after refresh

Tags: javascript, forms, refresh

First of all, here is the page: [Phyre.no/ask](http://phyre.no/ask/)

When you ask a question, the site will redirect you to ../ask/answer.html
If you refresh that page the answers disappear and will not show on the site again.

Probably caused by this:
[Click for screenshot](http://prntscr.com/26ybsx)

Feel free to take a look at the source code.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9269183/237312

Comment: How should I recreate my form?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you have problems in http://phyre.no/ask/refresh.js
See line 10... there should be a comma after the array value... after "Think about it."

Comment: Please set the answer as the correct answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it, as I pointed out in my comment, the commas are missing in refresh.js

I tried it on my desktop and it's working - CONFIRMED. Just put in all the commas correctly.

```
var textarray = [

 "Yes.",
 "No.",
 "Maybe.",
 "Very likely.",
 "Unlikely.",
 "Within the next few days you  will get the answer.",
 "Think about it.",
 "There is no chance.",
 "There is a possibility",
 "Positive.",
 "Negative."

];
```

Comment: I just fixed that. Still problems with the form after refresh. No idea how to implant the PRG.

Comment: there is still no comma after "Positive."